# Compare performance of JavaScript and Jquery code to defer images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two codes to defer images on website

```
function init() {
   var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
   for (var i=0; i<imgDefer.length; i++) {
   if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-defer')) {
   imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-defer'));
} } }
window.onload = init;
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('img').each(function(){
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-defer'));
   });
});
```

I want to know which one of these can perform better on client side in terms of

1. Speed
2. Resource consumption(specially on mobile devices)

Forget about the number of images, image sizes, server response time.

Comment: native javascript is faster than. Also in the jquery code there is not if loop which you have added in native javascript code

Comment: @brk jQuery version does not need an if block because it takes care of it internally.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem like there's a lot of difference between the two, but really what you're looking at is this part:

```
if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-defer')) {
  imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-defer'));
}
```

versus:

```
$(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-defer'));
```

The rest of the code is called only once, so it's not going to make a huge impact on performance in real life.

I doubt there's a decisive difference between the above two snippets.

You should measure everything in the profiler, of course.